# Cerberus API access with ruby/savon

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, savon

Guys I have got an issue with wsdl processing.
Cerberus FTP server has it's own wsdl API for server configuration
www.cerberusftp.com/support/help/webservices.htm
I tried to execute some functions with ruby and savon like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
require 'savon'
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://192.168.1.5:10001/wsdl/Cerberus.wsdl")
response = client.call(:server_information) do 

  message credentials:  {user: "admin", password: "123"}
end
```

From sniffer I can see POST request

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://cerberusllc.com/service/cerberusftpservice" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
- <env:Body>
- <tns:ServerInformationRequest>
- <tns:credentials>
  <tns:user>admin</tns:user> 
  <tns:password>123</tns:password> 
  </tns:credentials>
  </tns:ServerInformationRequest>
  </env:Body>
  </env:Envelope>
```

Also I tried tool Membarene SOAP client

```
<s12:Envelope xmlns:s12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>
  <s12:Body>
    <ns1:ServerInformationRequest xmlns:ns1='http://cerberusllc.com/service/cerberusftpservice'>
      <ns1:credentials xmlns:ns1='http://cerberusllc.com/common'>
        <ns1:user>admin</ns1:user>
        <ns1:password>123</ns1:password>
      </ns1:credentials>
    </ns1:ServerInformationRequest>
  </s12:Body>
</s12:Envelope>
```

It's POST request slightly different and it works.
Any idea how to do the same in ruby + savon ?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved that issue.
I generate XML query manually.
it looks like:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://example.com:10001/wsdl/Cerberus.wsdl")
variable = client.call(:add_group xml: "your xml " ) # you can generate this xml via SoapUI tool or Membarene SOAP client.
```

Answer (score -1):

My standard response:

1. download SoapUI
2. build a valid, successful call
3. rebuild in Ruby with Savon (not RoR)
4. ask questions here and you will receive help :-)